# Sum a variable across dataframes by an ID variable

Tags: r, sapply

There are 3 data frames. The ID variable is in the 12th column of each data frame. I created a vector `list_cc_q1` that contains all the unique IDs across all data frames (hence each entry in this vector appears in the 12th column of at least one data frame).

I wish to create a vector `v1` that adds, for each ID, the values in the 7th column from each data frame which contains that ID (hence `v1` would be of the same length as `list_cc_q1`). Here's the code I'm using:

```
f1 <- function(x,y){
      ifelse(length(get(y)[which(get(y)[x,12]),7])>0, get(y)[which(get(y)[x,12]),7], 0)}

g1 <- function(x){sum(sapply(ls()[1:3], function(y){ f1(x,y)}))}

v1 <- sapply(list_cc_q1, function(z){ g1(z) })
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error in get(y)[x, 12] : incorrect number of dimensions
Called from: which(get(y)[x, 12])
```

I think I've overcomplicated the code, a simpler method will be immensely helpful.

But why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly, but how about:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(value = c(df1[[7]],df2[[7]],df3[[7]]), id = c(df1[[12]],df2[[12]],df3[[12]]))
dt[, .(sum = sum(value)), by = id]
```

This concatenates the 7th column of each of the three data.frames (df1, df2, df3) to a value column and the 12th column of each of the data.frames (df1, df2, df3) to an id column to form a data.table with two columns (value and id). It then sums the value column by the id column.

EDIT: Your code might not work because of the

```
ls()[1:3]
```

The ls() command is executed in the function-environment which does not contain your three data.frames if I see this correctly. You can see this by comparing the following:

```
ls()[1:3]
# [1] "df1" "df2" "df3"
function_ls <- function(){cat(ls()[1:3])}
function_ls()
# NA NA NA
```

Comment: Perfect! You understand correctly. Corrected my code by using `ls(envir=.GlobalEnv)` [and another correction too regarding `which`]. But your code snippet is 2500 times faster. Thanks!